# Which user opens a file in python?

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services

I am working with django and celery. In my celery task, I instantiate a class and that class is responsible for generating and mailing a CSV file.
My problem is I am getting `IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied`
when i try to do `fp = open(filename, 'w')`. But how do I get to know which user of my server is trying to create that file and how can I provide that user with appropriate permissions.I am working on AWS server.
My code for writing files is this:

```
with open(filename, 'w') as f_pointer:
    os.chmod(filename, 777)
    myfile = csv.writer(f_pointer)
    myfile.writerow(columns)
    myfile.writerows(rows)
```

Thanks

Comment: `chmod 777` is an ugly hack.  Like leaving your door unlocked so you don't have to figure out how to use the key.  Learn about unix file permissions instead.  Can you provide information about how your'e executing the script and the path of `filename` for a good answer?

Comment: You need to provide the permission before opening the file. Try to move the os.chmod command prior to the opening of the file.

Comment: Log `getpass.getuser()` and then you'll know.

Comment: `os.chmod(filename, 777)` is just wrong. Maybe you mean `os.chmod(filename, 0o777)` ?

Answer (score 0):

First check the file permission or owner , then use the property permission.

ls -l filename

Another, you should check if this user can create the filename in the directory .

Answer (score 0):

The file is opened by the same user who is running the process. Now if the directory where you are creating the file or file you opening to write to are not writable by the user, then chmod will not work.

You'll have to chose the directory/file that is writable by the user.